# Pip installation error while installing cssmin 0.1.4

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use Flask-Social.
While installing [Flask Social Example](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-social-example) on a virtualenv, I got error for cssmin 0.1.4.

```
...
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How to fix this? Should I download cssmin source and install manually?

Comment: I've downloaded [cssmin-0.1.4.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/44/7c2cd397daedd9988e1715d8a46ffce9f1dc70d4edfa8fdf2b0e715ef9cf/cssmin-0.1.4.tar.gz) and extracted it. But running `pip install .` or `python setup.py install` raises the same error. Why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

try this out ...

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install cssmin -i  https://pypi.python.org/simple
```